# .Net 7 upgrade fails in Azure Devops build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, .net-7.0

Our .net 6 solution was recently upgraded to .net 7 and built successfully in local machine using VS 2022 version 17.5.4. But the same solution when running in a Azure Devops pipeline, it fails in the task, NugetCommand@2.

The error was, *error : Version 7.0.203 of the .NET SDK requires at least version 17.4.0 of MSBuild. The current available version of MSBuild is 16.11.2.50704. Change the .NET SDK specified in global.json to an older version that requires the MSBuild version currently available.*

Also, one thing that I found unusual was that the previous task in Azure Devops pipeline, NuGetToolInstaller@1 has the following in its log,

[image]

It is clear that msbuild with version 16.11.2.xxxx is loaded as the VS version used is 2019.

I am still not sure, how to get through this.

Comment: Are you using a private agent or a hosted agent?

Comment: @DanielMann How to check the agent type?

Comment: What is the name of the agent pool your pipeline is using?

Comment: @DanielMann The name of the agent pool is Azure Pipelines.

Comment: Use the `windows-2022` instead of the `windows-2019` image. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#designate-a-pool-in-your-pipeline

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion given by @DanielMann worked for me. I updated the azure pipeline yml file to use windows-2022 instead of windows-2019 and it worked like charm.

Thanks.